# What force would a cable winding onto a pulley experience?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, torque, string

I am quite confused about pulley problems with cable on only one side. Like how I draw here

[image: pulley problem]

The massless and frictionless pulley in blue with rotational inertia J and radius R is fixed on a platform with mass X. Assume the platform is constrained on both side so it could only move up and down frictionlessly. The massless cable in orange has a spring constant of K and are already stretched--to hold the platform--even when the pulley is not moving. The cable is connected to a rigid ceiling. When a torque Tau is supplied to the pulley to wind the cable into the pulley and move the platform up, should the tau be equal to the weight of the platform and the cable would be under 2*the weight of the platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't do that because torque and force/weight are different things. Different units. One cannot equal the other anymore than 2 apples equals 3 oranges.

The main thing that you need to get clear in your mind is that when lifting something or pushing something horizontally, as soon as you provide enough force to counteract gravity (when lifting) and friction (when pushing), you basically have something like an asteroid floating through deep space. Any extra force you apply in those directions goes purely to accelerating the object since the force of friction and gravity have already been nullified. all losses in the system that would decelerate things toward zero velocity have been nullified.

The torque is producing a force that acts at the rightmost point on the pulley to move everything up. It is THAT force (which I will henceforth refer to as the driving force) which you should be thinking about first, before the torque.

If the driving force is equal to the weight, then it will maintain the same velocity it had when the driving force became equal to the weight. Because no net forces exist to produce accelerations to speed things up in either direction. So it can neither speed up nor slow down. It just stays at whatever it was. This means that if it was moving upward at some velocity when the forces equalized, it would continue moving upward at that same velocity (kind of like a rock flying through deep space). If it was not moving when the forces equalized then it would remain where it was (as opposed to descending towards the ground).

If you increase the driving force a little bit more, that extra force goes solely to acceleration free of the influence of gravity, then you have a net acceleration $a$ upwards and it rises at an ever increasing speed. This would cause the rope to experience a force $F=m(g+a)$ which is more than if the pulley was just hanging there motionless.

If you decrease the driving force a little it would descend slowly at an acceleration of $a$. Similarly, the rope experienced a force $F=m(g-a)$.

If you decrease the driving force to zero it will enter free-fall and accelerate towards the ground at $g$ and the force on the rope is zero since $F=m(g-a) = m(g-g)=0$

You can then easily figure out what torque is required to produce that driving force at that point.

It's really similar, if not identical, to a problem where a wheel is rolling horizontally on the ground against a force that is continuously pushing in the opposite direction.

---

What I am talking about above is the steady state response. After the string stretch as stabilized to a new equilibrium under the applied force. But there is a transient response that decays to zero over time where the string stretch is changing as it tries to find an equilibrium. If you have solve the differential equations for the system both the transient and steady state response will pop out naturally.

Upon initial application of torque, the system should accelerate up but the stretching string will cause the acceleration to be slower than what it would be at steady state. At some point, the string will be stretched to a length LONGER than what it is at steady state and will begin to contract. The stretch in the string at equilibrium is longer than it was while it was just hanging there not moving, but shorter than maximum length that occurs during the transient response.

Comment: But there is elasticity in the cable. Wouldn't the cable just elongate and pull at the pulley (when the pulley is trying to pull the cable downward, the tension in the cable will try to pull itself upward) at the same amount of force the pulley generates?

Comment: @user39178 The string stretches or unstretches whenever there is a change in the equilibrium of forces which will serve to reduce the acceleration in whatever direction the acceleration is acting. This is the transient response. However once the string has finished stretched to a new equilibrium the forces will be as described above so long as the acceleration/force remains the same. This is the steady state response which is what I described above.

Comment: If you want the complete response including the transient response using the force and torque relationships I described above and solve the differential equations still according to the concepts above and both the transient and steady state response will pop out of it.

Comment: so even  if the torque could provide a force equal to the weight of the system, as long as rotation is also supplied--like if a motor is the torque provider--then the platform would still go up because the pulley is winding cable at constant angular velocity, right?

Comment: @user39178 If the torque provided produced a force at the pulley edge exactly equal to the weight of the system, the system would maintain whatever velocity it had when those conditions were met. Because all losses in the system that would decelerate things toward zero velocity have been nullified. At the same time, no net forces exist to produce accelerations to speed things up in either direction. So it can neither speed up nor slow down. It just stays at whatever it was.

Comment: @user39178 The possibility also exists that the string may stretch to a longer length that what it ultimately stabilizes at. The stabilized stretch would be longer than the stretch while it was just sitting there. That would equate to an decaying oscillation in the stretch upon application of torque to move up. However, it is not clear in my mind if that happens in your scenario (or if it happens if you raise a block hanging from a spring). It does happen if you have to blocks connected by a spring and you start dragging one of them horizontally.

Comment: There was a question for the horizontal block dragging problem on the Engineer or Physics Stack exchange which seems to have been deleted. You had to solve with energy to find the spring stretch at steady state. If you tried to directly use FBD diagrams without partial differential equations you get the wrong answer because you would end up with something more like the maximum spring length during the transient oscillation rather than the steady state spring length. You needed to solve the partial differential equations of the FBD.